# How to handle an "infinite" IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, enumeration, infinite-loop, yield-return

A trivial example of an "infinite" IEnumerable would be

```
IEnumerable<int> Numbers() {
  int i=0;
  while(true) {
    yield return unchecked(i++);
  }
}
```

I know, that

```
foreach(int i in Numbers().Take(10)) {
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

and

```
var q = Numbers();
foreach(int i in q.Take(10)) {
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

both work fine (and print out the number 0-9).

But are there any pitfalls when copying or handling expressions like `q`? Can I rely on the fact, that they are always evaluated "lazy"? Is there any danger to produce an infinite loop?

Comment: Just to be picky, wouldn't your "infinite" example throw an exception when i = Int32.MaxValue and you do i++?  Or does it cycle through to Int32.MinValue?  Hmm.....

Comment: You are right. It will probably throw an overflow exception ... I'll edit it.

Comment: Just being picky here, your point still came across.  :)  Also, I tried it and it does loop to Int32.MinValue.  No OverflowException, so it was in fact an infinite loop.

Comment: C# compiles without overflow checking by default. the safe way is always to write unchecked(i++) because you could compile with /checked, and then it would puke. Using unchecked() tells the compiler it is ok if an overflow occurs even if compiled with /checked.

Comment: Than back to the more beautiful original :D

Comment: Aha, I learn something new every day.  I know in assembly you don't have any overflow checking, I thought C# would have it, being a "higher level" language, but I guess it's optional.  I think using unchecked() also makes your intentions clear, which is always a good thing.   And I think it's unchecked { }, not unchecked( ).  :)

Comment: @Nelson: no, both `unchecked {}` and `unchecked()` are allowed in c#. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I sincerly hope that code like this NEVER makes it into a production app that you're working on.  If it does it belongs in the Daily WTF.

Comment: @Josiah: Well it is a nice feature supporting a stream-like view on data. For example receiving network data or parsing a log file or random number generation or ...

Comment: @dalo, the link Philip posted says: "If neither checked nor unchecked is used, a constant expression uses the default overflow checking at compile time, which is checked."  This contradicts with what you said, but on a default WPF project template, it did not give me an OverflowException.  I don't know who's finally right.

Comment: @Nelson: It doesn't "contradict with what I said" because the expression isn't a constant expression. It cannot be evaluated at compile time. Hence, the compiler options influence the overflow checking, and for any version of the C# compiler available until today, the checking is turned off by default, hence NO overflow exception (in VB the behavior is different).

Comment: Good point.  short x = 32767 + 10; says "Constant value '32777' cannot be converted to a 'short'.  I'm guessing that's an example of "overflow checking" in a constant expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are guaranteed that the code above will be executed lazily. While it looks (in your code) like you'd loop forever, your code *actually* produces something like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> Numbers()
{
    return new PrivateNumbersEnumerable();
}

private class PrivateNumbersEnumerable : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() 
    { 
        return new PrivateNumbersEnumerator(); 
    }
}

private class PrivateNumbersEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
{
    private int i;

    public bool MoveNext() { i++; return true; }   

    public int Current
    {
        get { return i; }
    }
}
```

(This obviously isn't *exactly* what will be generated, since this is pretty specific to your code, but it's nonetheless similar and should show you why it's going to be lazily evaluated).

Answer (score 23):

As long as you only call lazy, un-buffered methods you should be fine. So `Skip`, `Take`, `Select`, etc are fine. However, `Min`, `Count`, `OrderBy` etc would go crazy.

It can work, but you need to be cautious. Or inject a `Take(somethingFinite)` as a safety measure (or some other custom extension method that throws an exception after too much data).

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SanityCheck<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, int max) {
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T item in data) {
        if(++i >= max) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I have a competing answer, but I just have to give an upvote for an extension method for IEnumerable called *SanityCheck*.  Best function name ever.  I'm gonna go implement that . . .

Comment: +1 for pointing this out. Also if the OP actually call `foreach(int i in Numbers())` that would also cause problems.

Answer (score 5):

You would have to avoid any greedy functions that attempt to read to end.  This would include `Enumerable` extensions like: `Count`, `ToArray`/`ToList`, and aggregates `Avg`/`Min`/`Max`, etc.

There's nothing wrong with infinite lazy lists, but you must make conscious decisions about how to handle them.

Use `Take` to limit the impact of an endless loop by setting an upper bound even if you don't need them all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code will always work without infinite looping.  Someone might come along though later and mess things up.  Suppose they want to do:

```
var q = Numbers().ToList();
```

Then, you're hosed!  Many "aggregate" functions will kill you, like `Max()`.

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't lazy evaluation, your first example won't work as expected in the first place.