# How to convert tuple list to list tuple?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, tuples, deconstructor

For example, I have an `IEnumerable<(int, char)> list`. How to convert `list` into `(IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<char>)`?

Is there a fast way to do this? It would be better to work with `System.Linq`.

Comment: As a side note, calling a `IEnumerable<(int, char)>` "list" might be confusing. Lists are materialized collections in .NET. An `IEnumerable<(int, char)>` might well be a deferred enumerable sequence, containing elements that are not stored in the RAM, and instead they are fetched/generated one by one while the sequence is enumerated. A better name for the `list` variable would be `sequence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues to consider:

1. You don't want to iterate over the input more than once.
2. You want to size the returned lists to the correct length when creating them if possible, to avoid multiple list resizing.

To efficiently find the length of an `IEnumerable<T>` you can use the .NET 6 [`Enumerable.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.trygetnonenumeratedcount?view=net-6.0).

Note that of course this will not work for some `IEnumerable` types, but it will work in many cases.

Also note that for small list sizes, calling `Enumerable.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount()` will likely make things slower, since a default-sized list would probably already be big enough to prevent resizing.

A method using this would look something like this:

```
public static (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>) Deconstruct<T,U>(IEnumerable<(T,U)> sequence)
{
    List<T> listT;
    List<U> listU;

    if (sequence.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(out int count))
    {
        listT = new List<T>(count);
        listU = new List<U>(count);
    }
    else
    {
        listT = new List<T>();
        listU = new List<U>();
    }

    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        listT.Add(item.Item1);
        listU.Add(item.Item2);
    }

    return (listT, listU);
}
```

This code isn't very elegant because there's no short way of writing the code to initialise the lists to the correct size. But it is probably about as efficient as you are likely to get.

You could possibly make it slightly more performant by returning arrays rather than lists if you know the count:

```
public static (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>) Deconstruct<T,U>(IEnumerable<(T,U)> sequence)
{
    if (sequence.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(out int count))
    {
        var arrayT = new T[count];
        var arrayU = new U[count];

        int i = 0;

        foreach (var item in sequence)
        {
            arrayT[i] = item.Item1;
            arrayU[i] = item.Item2;
            ++i;
        }

        return (arrayT, arrayU);
    }
    else
    {
        var listT = new List<T>();
        var listU = new List<U>();

        foreach (var item in sequence)
        {
            listT.Add(item.Item1);
            listU.Add(item.Item2);
        }

        return (listT, listU);
    }
}
```

I would only go to such lengths if performance testing indicated that it's worth it!

Comment: That's inspiring. I've got another question for you: will it bring apparent extra costs if I use `foreach (var (t, u) in sequence)` instead?

Comment: I don't think using `foreach (var (t, u) in sequence)` will noticeably slow things down, (and may even make it faster) but if in doubt use [Benchmark.Net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) to test it!

Comment: OK, I wondered because that will call the `Deconstruct` method with 2 `out` parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple with Aggregate:

```
IEnumerable<(int, char)> list = new[]
{
    (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'),
};

(List<int> ints, List<char> chars) =
    list.Aggregate((new List<int>(), new List<char>()), (a, x) =>
    {
        a.Item1.Add(x.Item1);
        a.Item2.Add(x.Item2);
        return a;
    });
```

That gives:

[image: output]

That's the fastest way, but this is simpler:

```
List<int> ints = list.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList();
List<char> chars = list.Select(x => x.Item2).ToList();
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is better than a `foreach` block

Comment: Sorry Enigmativity, it's my bad, you are using ValueTuple, so it is fine.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do this without having to materialize the source enumerable. Will probably require some custom enumerator.

Comment: @KlausGütter - Isn't this exactly what the enumerator is for? And `Aggregate` only runs one, so it's fairly efficient.

Comment: @Enigmativity what I mean is: Enumerable.Aggregate fully enumerates the source (runs through all the elements) before it returns its result. This would strictly speaking not be necessary to construct the desired tuple of projected enumerables. It is not as efficient as it could be in the case where the source enumerable contains lots of elements (which might be expecive to enumerate) but the user intends to enumerate only part of the result enumerables.

Answer (score 0):

If the original is a materialized collection like `List<(int, char)>` or `(int, char)[]` you can do the following:

```
var result = (list.Select(i => i.Item1), list.Select(i => i.Item2));
```

If the original is just an `IEnumerable<(int, char)>`, you should convert it to a `List` first (otherwise the source will get enumerated twice):

```
var list = source.ToList();
```

There are cases where this (and all other answers up to now):

- does not work at all: when the source is an [infinite sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740001/how-to-handle-an-infinite-ienumerable)
- or is inefficient: if the source sequence is big, but you intend to enumerate only a few elements of each of the result enumerables

**If this is of no concern for the use case given, stop reading here.**

It is possible to overcome this restriction with some implementation effort. Basically, the "derived enumerables" have to be implemented in a way that they request just the required items from the source enumerable and no more.

The following solution uses a class `TupleEnumerable` to fetch only the required elements from the the source and remembering the fetched elements for use by the two derived enumerables.

```
public class TupleEnumerable<T1, T2> : IDisposable
{
    readonly IEnumerator<(T1, T2)> _source;
    readonly List<(T1, T2)> _preFetched = new();
    private bool _finished;

    public TupleEnumerable(IEnumerable<(T1, T2)> source)
    {
        _source = source.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _source.Dispose();
        _preFetched.Clear();
        _finished = true;
    }

    // Try to get the element if it already has been fetched
    // or otherwise use the source enumerator to fetch more.
    private bool TryGet(int index, out (T1, T2) tuple)
    {
        if (index < _preFetched.Count)
        {
            tuple = _preFetched[index];
            return true;
        }

        if (_finished)
        {
            tuple = default;
            return false;
        }

        _finished = !_source.MoveNext();
        if (_finished)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("**Source finished");
            tuple = default;
            return false;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"**Source: {_source.Current}");

        _preFetched.Add(_source.Current);
        tuple = _source.Current;
        return true;
    }

    // This method returns a tuple of "derived" enumerables
    public (IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>) GetEnumerables()
        => (new ProjectedEnumerable<T1>(this, t => t.Item1),
            new ProjectedEnumerable<T2>(this, t => t.Item2));

    // This is our own implementation of IEnumerator<T>
    class ProjectedEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly TupleEnumerable<T1, T2> _tupleEnumerable;
        private readonly Func<(T1, T2), T> _projection;

        public ProjectedEnumerable(TupleEnumerable<T1, T2> tupleEnumerable, Func<(T1, T2), T> projection)
        {
            _tupleEnumerable = tupleEnumerable;
            _projection = projection;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new ProjectedEnumerator<T>(_tupleEnumerable, _projection);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    // This is our own implementation of IEnumerable<T>
    class ProjectedEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly TupleEnumerable<T1, T2> _tupleEnumerable;
        private readonly Func<(T1, T2), T> _projection;
        private int _index;
        private T _current;

        public ProjectedEnumerator(TupleEnumerable<T1, T2> tupleEnumerable, Func<(T1, T2), T> projection)
        {
            _tupleEnumerable = tupleEnumerable;
            _projection = projection;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_tupleEnumerable.TryGet(_index, out var current))
            {
                _current = _projection(current);
                _index++;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                _current = default;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _index = 0;
            _current = default;
        }

        public T Current => _current;

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<(int, char)> list = new[]
{
    (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')
};

using var c = new TupleEnumerable<int, char>(list);
var (enumerable1, enumerable2) = c.GetEnumerables();
```

Note: As Theodor Zoulia pointed out in the comments: the semantics of the TupleEnumerable<T1, T2> is different from a standard enumerable. Enumerating a TupleEnumerable<T1, T2> any number of times, will result in a single enumeration of the underlying source. It effectively doubles as a [memoizer](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/System/Linq/Operators/Memoize.cs).

Comment: This solution calls select twice, is it efficient?

Comment: As `list` is assumed to be already materialized: yes. The Select is just a trivial member access to the tuple member in memory.

Comment: What's the problem that the `TupleEnumerable<T1, T2>` is attempting to solve? If the idea is to avoid storing everything in a `List<(T1, T2)>`, you are doing it anyway in the `_preFetched` field. You are just delaying the inevitable IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias If the source enumerable can deliver one million elements and enumerating each element takes 1 ms, but in the end you want to enumerate only the first 5 elements of each of the derived enumerables, this makes a difference of 1000 seconds vs. 5 ms. So indeed, it makes no difference if the usage pattern is to complete enumerate everything, but that is not neccessarily so.

Comment: It should be noted that the semantics of the `TupleEnumerable<T1, T2>` are different from a standard enumerable. Enumerating a `TupleEnumerable<T1, T2>` any number of times, will result in a single enumeration of the underlying source. It effectively doubles as a [memoizer](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/System/Linq/Operators/Memoize.cs).